# Combine dataframe from two list to a single list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have two lists containing multiple dataframes `listA` and `listB`. The first list has 5 dataframe, and the second list has 3 dataframe. I want to form a third list `listC` where it contains the dataframes from both list such that I will have 8 dataframes in total in `listC`. I tried using `merge()`, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: give a code example please

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function to use is `append()`:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2))

l1 <- list(df, df, df, df)
l2 <- list(df, df)
l3 <- append(l1, l2)
```